# Why some functions cannot be folded in vscode python?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

There are some functions in my code that I cannot fold and unfold them ,this problem remains for newly defined functions too. I check indentation before and after them but no unusual indentation found.
The grip which is used for folding and unfolding is not available for them.
But for my old functions they are available and folding and unfolding works.
I tried formatting my document which is available with Shift+Alt+F in vs-code but it didn't help.
My vs-code version is 1.72.0 and python 3.9.10 .

[image: part of my code which shows grips]